# Create an Array string for table layout

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to pass a list of data from my php to populate my table layout, am presently using volley to connect to my server side. How do i set this list

Am making use of codecrafters library and they have a tutorial on how to populate the table which works for me but the problem is the items they used were manually typed and not gotten dynamically from a server, so am having issues implementing this same code for data that comes from a server

Their string looks like this

```
   static String[][] spaceProbes={
         {"1","Pioneer","Chemical","Jupiter"},
         {"2","Voyager","Plasma","Andromeda"},
         {"3","Casini","Solar","Saturn"},
         {"4","Spitzer","Anti-Matter","Andromeda"},
         {"5","Apollo","Chemical","Moon"},
          {"6","Curiosity","Solar","Mars"},


     };
```

and they populate it into the layout using

```
      tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(MainActivity.this, spaceProbes));
```

am presently using this array string but it returns the last item in the array only

```
       try {
                //converign the strign to json assary object

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                //traversing through all teh objects
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    //getting product object from json array

                    JSONObject allClass = array.getJSONObject(i);

                  takin = new String[]{allClass.getString("numb"),
                            allClass.getString("name"),
                            allClass.getString("time")};

                }


                tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(AttendanceActivity.this, Collections.singletonList(takin)));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How do i recreate the same structure as spaceProbes but this time from the server

Comment: Why did you use the [android-studio] tag on this? Did you read the tag description?

Comment: yes i did, this is android studio @EJoshuaS

Comment: The tag usage guidance is as follows: "Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE by Google targeted at Android app development. **Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use the Android tag.**" This question is about general Android programming, not Android Studio.

Comment: okay thank you @EJoshuaS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reset the value of `takin` every time when you do

```
takin = new String[]{allClass.getString("numb"),
                        allClass.getString("name"),
                        allClass.getString("time")};
```

Instead, try this,

```
String[][] takin = new String[array.length()][3]
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject allClass = array.getJSONObject(i);
    takin[i] = new String[]{allClass.getString("numb"),
                        allClass.getString("name"),
                        allClass.getString("time")};

}
tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(AttendanceActivity.this, Collections.singletonList(takin)));
```